# bactch print for "Outlook calendar printing assistant"

Tags: outlook, calendar, printing

I'm using "Outlook calendar printing assistant" to organize my daily work list, then print it out every morning, just wondering if the print job can be done automatically through some kind of batch command line?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can either use macros to script Outlook externally via automation, or you could build an addin.

You would collect the appointments for the day and use [`AppointmentItem.PrintOut()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175146.aspx).

But before you go for that you should take a look to see if there isn't already an addin which does what you need.

Comment: Thanks gf, but "Outlook calendar printing assistant" is a standalone application outside outlook, the best feature is that it can print mulitples calendars and lots of print templates. I'm not sure it can accept Macros.

Comment: BTW, I should check if any add-ins available. Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding Macros: i was talking about Outlook. The printing assistant probably only uses Outlook via Automation as well.